# meteorjs how to nest handlebars_helpers into template

Tags: meteor

I have these two handlebars-helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("trim", function(input, length) {
    if (input) {
        console.log(length);
        return input.substring(0,length) + " ..."
    }
});

Handlebars.registerHelper("__", function(input) {

    var language = TAPi18n.getLanguage();
    if (language) {
        return input[language];
    } else {
        return input + ".nl"
    }
});
```

I would like to use them like this in my templates:

```
{{trim {{__ DescriptionA}} 100}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this is on the Meteor roadmap at some point but this is currently unavailable.

A possible workaround is to merge your helpers into a single one :

```
Template.registerHelper("trim__",function(input,length){
  var language = TAPi18n.getLanguage();
  var result = language ? input[language] : input + ".nl";
  return input.substring(0,length) + " ...";
});
```